# Counting attribute in raster?

Tags: arcpy, python

I'm trying to calculate the total number of counts a raster contains using python script. When I ran the script, I didn't get any error. However, I also didn't get the number of counts for each row in the attribute table.

Code:

```
import arcpy

#To overwrite output
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Subhasis/Test/raster-read"

#Build Raster Attribute Table
arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("sti-9", "Overwrite")

# loop through attribute table
Rows = arcpy.SearchCursor( "sti-9" ) 

for row in Rows:
    count = row.getValue( "COUNT" ) 
    print count
```

Comment: If you view the VAT that you are creating, does it have a populated count field?

Comment: Yes, When I open the raster file in GIS, I see the attribute table having counts for each row

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the field in a VAT is `Count` and it's case sensitive. Try:

```
Rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("sti-9") 

for row in Rows:
    count = row.getValue("Count") 
    print count

del row, Rows
```

For Arcgis 10.1+

```
with arpcy.da.SearchCursor("sti-9", ("Count")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        count = row[0]
        print count
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I incorporated your code and ran it. I didn't get any error message. But still, I am n't getting the counts for each row in my python shell window. Thanks!

Comment: @Inception, Are you running this from within Arcmap? Add you raster to the map and reference the layer instead of the absolute path.

Comment: Yes, I was running outside the Arcmap

Comment: @Inception, try it from within the python window in ArcMap and reference a layer (you can drag-n-drop) from the TOC.